# Finding direction of rejection in the wilcoxon signed-rank test method in scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

Given two arrays of paired data:

```
import numpy, scipy
A = numpy.array([18.3, 13.3, 16.5, 12.6, 9.5, 13.6, 8.1, 8.9, 10.0, 8.3, 7.9, 8.1, 13.4])  
B = numpy.array([12.7, 11.1, 15.3, 12.7, 10.5, 15.6, 11.2, 14.2, 16.2, 15.5, 19.9, 20.4, 36.8])
```

Using the wilcoxon method from scipy : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wilcoxon.html

```
print(scipy.stats.wilcoxon(A, B))  
#outputs: WilcoxonResult(statistic=16.0, pvalue=0.039243276150326668)
```

When using a significant of 5% this null-hypothesis will be rejected.
My question is: **How can I see which direction is responsible for the rejection?**

Comment: As far as I know, you can't tell. Reversing `A` and `B` results in the same answer. Also, from the linked documentation it returns "*The sum of the ranks of the differences above or below zero, whichever is smaller.*". If the direction is important to you, you could program it yourself, I guess..